# Read xlsx file content to store in an array using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, xlsx

How to read the content of xlsx file and store into an array using plain javascript,I don't want to use any third party libraries.Please help

Comment: XLSX files are rather complex. They're essentially archives of many sub files made up of XML if i remember correctly. I would highly advise using a third party library for this purpose. You should try and open the XLSX file with an archive viewer such as 7zip or winrar to get an understanding of the file structure.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried

Comment: I am using Sheetjs library to read the data now. Looks that's doing this job great.